# nested divs and dojo datagrid

Tags: html, dojox.grid.datagrid

I'm having trouble getting some divs and a datagrid sorted out.  I've got too many scroll bars.
[image: too many scroll bars]

Am I wrong to think some of the divs/content panes could be combined?

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="rightPane" region="right">
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer">
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="DownLinePane" title ="DownLine 
          Reps" selected="true" style="overflow:hidden;">
      <div id="DownLine" style="overflow:hidden; height:100%; width:100%; display:none;">
        <table data-dojo-type="dojox.grid.DataGrid" data-dojo-id="DLgrid" id="DLgrid" 
          sortInfo="3" data-dojo-props="rowsPerPage:'15', rowSelector:'20px'">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th field="rep_no" width="60px" height="80px">
              Rep Number
              </th>
              <th field="name" width="110px">
              Name
              </th>
              <th field="gen" width="37px">
              Gen#
              </th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- end of downline div -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of downlinePane div -->
  </div>
  <!-- end of accordion -->
</div>
```